# Android on VMWare or VirtualBox

Tags: android, image, vmware, virtualbox

Can Android OS that is installed on actual devices be emulated in VMWare or VirtualBox. Are there any such distros or images available?

Comment: The Android SDK comes with its own emulator, so I'm not sure why you'd need the virtualization. Either way, this is probably a better question for Serverfault, as it's not exactly programming-related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a project called live-android. I think, this is what you are seeking.

http://code.google.com/p/live-android/

Answer (score 3):

There is a new project called Android x86
http://www.android-x86.org

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide.. [Installing Android on Vmware, Virtulbox](http://www.taranfx.com/how-to-run-google-android-in-virtualbox-vmware-on-netbooks)
I recommend virtualbox for performance